# Unit test constructor that throws error

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a constructor that injects a configuration object. I am doing some validation on the object in the constructor. If the validation fails, i want to throw a error describing for the user what went wrong.

How do i test this with **Angular** and **Jasmine**?

Here is how i do it now, but this returns a failed test:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AwsCognitoService } from './aws-cognito.service';
import { AWS_COGNITO_CONFIG, AwsCognitoConfig } from './aws-cognito.config';

describe('AwsCognitoService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AwsCognitoService,
        {
          provide: AWS_COGNITO_CONFIG,
          useValue: new AwsCognitoConfig({
            region: 'eu-west-1'
          })
        }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should throw error when missing userPoolId or identityPoolId', inject(
    [AwsCognitoService],
    (service: AwsCognitoService) => {
        expect(service).toThrowError('Missing required configuration property: userPoolId or identityPoolId');
    }
  ));
});
```

Full test source: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-tdv3ew?file=app%2Faws-cognito.service.spec.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-5hc8t5?file=app/aws-cognito.service.spec.ts)

As you may know, constructors are called when you create a new instance of the class.

Jasmine's `expect` function can accept a function and isolate it, allowing you to expect after that.

With this syntax, you create an isolated function that Jasmine can monitor. And as you can see, your test is passing.

```
it('should throw error with missing param', () => {
  expect(() => new AwsCognitoService({} as any)).toThrowError();
});
```

Comment: By the way, +1 for the stackblitz of the test, it's already rare enough to have a [mcve], but one with tests ... Kudos !

Comment: I am the one that should say thank you! Marking it as the correct answer.